# In Ruby, how to prompt user to select from a list of options?

Tags: ruby, command

I've come across a gem that does what I want [here](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) but I'm curious if I can do this natively.

For example:

```
> ruby some_file.rb

Choose a fruit

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Kewi

> 1

What color?

1. Green
2. Red

> 2

Are you sure you want to create a Red Apple [y/n]?

> y

Creating Red Apple ...
```

Comment: Yes you can. Basic input/output can be achieved via `gets` and `puts`. If you have more ambitious goals, you should ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to print a title. This can be done via [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#puts-method):

```
puts "Choose a fruit"
```

Output:

```
Choose a fruit
```

Then for [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#each-method) option, you have to print a (1-based) number and its index. The latter can be added via [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html#with_index-method):

```
options = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kewi']

options.each.with_index(1) do |option, index|
  puts "#{index}. #{option}"
end
```

Output:

```
1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Kewi
```

Finally you have to prompt the user for input. You can use [`print`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#print-method) to output a string *without* adding a newline and then call [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#gets-method) to gather input:

```
print '> '
input = gets
```

Output: (that `▏` is supposed to be the cursor)

`> ▏`  
`> h▏`  <kbd>h</kbd>
`> hi▏` <kbd>i</kbd>
`> hi`  <kbd>enter</kbd>

Afterwards, `input` is set to `"hi\n"`. Note that `gets` will return a *string* which includes the newline character `\n` from <kbd>enter</kbd> by default.

Since you're interested in numeric input here, you can use [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#to_i-method) to convert the string to an integer. In addition, you can [`loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#loop-method) until the value is [`between?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Comparable.html#between-3F-method) 1 and 3 (the number of options):

```
loop do
  print '> '
  choice = gets.to_i
  break if choice.between?(1, options.size)

  puts 'Enter a value between 1 and #{options.size}'
end
```

Example:

```
> 5
Enter a value between 1 and 3
> foo
Enter a value between 1 and 3
> 2
```

`foo` gets rejected because `to_i` returns `0` for non-numeric strings and 0 is not between 1 and 3.

This should get you started. You probably want to move all of the above (print title, show options, gather input) into a single method which just returns the user's selection. In the end, it could work like this:

```
fruit = select('Choose a fruit', ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kewi'])
color = select('What color?', ['Green', 'Red'])

puts "Creating #{color} #{fruit}"
```